# is the set of all $n×n$ matrices with trace zero is nowhere dense?

Tags: general-topology

Is the set of all $n×n$ matrices with trace zero is nowhere dense?

---

I guess it is true as the image space is nowhere dense in $\mathbb{R}$. but can anybody confirm me please

Comment: It's a hyperplane...

Comment: Nowhere dense in what? Surely the set is everywhere dense in itself in the usual topology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set of matrices with trace zero is closed, because the trace is continuous. So you only have to show that the interior of your set is empty, and because the trace is linear, it is sufficient to find a sequence of matrices with nonzero trace convering to $0$.